# Visual Studio 2015 multiple solutions strategy (TFS)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs

What is the best strategy when having multiple solutions where some projects in a solution make a reference to an assembly of another project in another solution.

```
- Solution 1
-- Proj1
-- Proj2
- Solution 2
- OtherProj 1
- Solution 3
- FooProj1
- FooProj2
```

For example if OtherProj, FooProj1 and FooProj2 use Proj1 or Proj2 assemblies.

Now I have to build for example Proj1 and manually copy/paste that assembly to a solution folder in Solution 2 and Solution 3.
I can't reference directly, because that would use a local path and if I check in via source control (TFS) my colleague receives my local path (that is why we copy/paste in the solution folder so that the path is always relative).

What we were thinking of is adding a post build event and copy the assemblies to a shared folder on a server \myserver\assemblies\relaase\Proj1.dll and then reference to these files in our solution/project.

Would that be a good strategy, because it would work also with source control, or are there any other strategies to work?

(Something exists like Shared Projects in Visual Studio, but I think that is more for a single solution but multiple platforms instead of sharing around)

Comment: Once your code base gets big enough, it makes having a single SLN file unmanageable. At that point you need to write and maintain an MSBUILD ".proj" file to build all the projects in the right order. If you do that, your project can reference the DLLs from the place where they are built. You do NOT need to use absolute file paths for references - you should use relative paths (which is the default when creating a reference to another assembly, so you shouldn't need to do anything special here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should publish the output of each project/solution as a Nuget Package and take dependencies on those packages.

It is very easy to have the output of your Project or Solution packaged as a Nuget Package with most of the capabilities built in. A NuGet Repository can be a Network Share or you can use a hosted service (MyGet, VSTS/TFS, others).

Comment: Publishing Nuget packages is fine for CI builds, but what about when you need to make changes in one solution (SolutionA) while working in another solution, SolutionB,  that references SolutionA? Besides temporarily replacing the Nuget package reference in SolutionB with a local reference (a pain in the neck and subject to accidental commits of that local reference), what other options are there?

Comment: You treat each solution as a third party package with loose coupling. What you describe is tight coupling of code. Not a good practice...

Comment: This has nothing to do with coupling. It has to do with development in which you are working on, for example, a library and an application that uses it, at the same time. You need to make changes in the library and see/use them immediately in the application. Publishing to a Nuget repo is a sledgehammer, and espeically painful if Nuget doesn't support something akin to Maven's SNAPSHOT versions. If Nuget had that, it would be at least feasible to publish the library on every build.

Comment: It is recommended to use package management to manage dependancies. You can make a change and have it published in an automated pipeline, make it minutes of a turn around. If you need a tighter turn-around you can add a local Nuget package repo and have the packages published there.

Answer (score 0):

The VS extension, **NuGet Reference Switcher** is one solution for this situation. From it's description:

> NuGet Reference Switcher is a Visual Studio extension which automatically switches NuGet assembly references to project references and vice-versa. This is useful when developing applications which reference own NuGet packages.

[Here is the VS 2015 version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2015).

[Here is the VS 2017 version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RicoSuter.NuGetReferenceSwitcherforVisualStudio2017).